# Can't Load And Parse DOM Object

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to load a dom object and to parse it for finding specific links
Here is my code:

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/example.php");
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
 var_dump($dom);
```

What I get is:

> object(DOMDocument)#1 (0) { }

If i echo the $content I get all the html.

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code .. that looks perfectly fine.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, but there's probably something wrong with your assumption of what `var_dump` should produce here. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example from the manual: [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

```
<?php 
$content = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/example.php");
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadHTML($content);

// Empty array to hold all links to return
$links = array();

//Loop through each <a> tag in the dom and add it to the link array
foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    $links[] = array('url' => $link->getAttribute('href'), 'text' => $link->nodeValue);
}

print_r($links);
?>
```

Comment: np, Have a ponder at the manuals link, gives some great examples

Answer (score 1):

Instead of var_dump($xml)
try:
echo $xml->saveHTML();